# How to write form action in html/php code in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, controller, routes, action, livesearch

I am working on the **live search of an HTML form** in which **if I type La**, everything should show up related to La. **For Example:** La Man, La Fa etc.

The HTML code which I have used for that are:

```
<form autocomplete="off" id="search_form" method="GET" action="/search/helloWorld/{chars}">
   <div  style="padding-top:18%;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
      <!--           
         <div class="dates">
           <div class="start_date" style="width:50%;margin-right:3%;">
              <input readonly="readonly" class="form-control start_date  mb-4" type="text" placeholder="start date" id="startdate_datepicker">
           </div>
           <div class="end_date" style="width:50%;margin-left:3%;">
              <input readonly="readonly" class="form-control  end_date  mb-4" type="text" placeholder="end date" id="enddate_datepicker">
           </div>
         </div>
         -->
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default start_search_button" style="padding-left:12%;padding-right:12%;background-color: rgb(247, 144, 99);" >start search</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

The routing which I have done for the routes.php file is:

```
//helloworld routes
Route::get('search/helloWorld/{chars}','SearchController@helloWorld');
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering if I have written `action="/search/helloWorld/{chars}">` in the right way in the html code above. Do we write form action by seeing the routes in in Laravel (5) ?

Comment: can you please be specific about your current laravel version ? 5.1 or 5.2 or .. something else

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih Laravel 5.4 Have I done the routing in the right way?

Comment: i will write you my response. please edit your question because in laravel 5.4 we don't have routes.php instead of it we have web.php

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih I am using routes.php I have a feeling I told you the wrong version. I will check again

Comment: you can find the right version within composer.json file please

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih Does knowing laravel version matter ? I am using routes.php. After checking composre.json file,I found  `"require": {
  "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
  "watson/sitemap": "^2.0"
 },`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177881/discussion-between-thamer-belfkih-and-flash).

Answer (score 0):

If u are using laravel 5.4, try this:
Add name to your route for convenient mapping like so:

```
Route::get ('/search/helloworld/{id}', Controller@method)->name ('search');
```

Then in your form,map your action to the name of the route;

```
<form action="{{ route ('search', $char->id) }}">
```

etc..

Please replace my $char->Id with your real params

Sorry im sending this on a mobile.Hope it helps.